# Permission denied while saving image GD php

Tags: php, vps

I got permission denied error when I try to save GD image on my server

> failed to open stream: Permission denied Warning: imagejpeg(/home/admin/web/funpics.online/public_html/apps/ClashOfClans_/echo/71e2332a35deb0c1eef523126a13dfeb.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Comment: Well then set proper permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Change folder permissions:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 ~/web/funpics.online/public_html/apps/ClashOfClans_/echo
```

Or you can change folder's owner:

if http user is `www-data`

```
sudo chown -R www-data:your_user ~/web/funpics.online/public_html/apps/ClashOfClans_/echo
```

Comment: Can you show us folder permissions by executing `ls -la ~/web/funpics.online/public_html/apps/ClashOfClans_/echo`

Comment: drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Nov  1 10:06 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root  4096 Nov  1 10:06 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 71816 Nov  1 10:06 be7f92c1b358eb4ce2bd82d657e831d6.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 73369 Nov  1 10:06 ed2b18d046ce4ed3a456409c4a6e026e.jpg
and its not in root folder ~ is target for root its is etc/home/admin

Comment: drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Nov  1 10:06 echo

Comment: okay this will work with 777 permission i give 777 permission to echo folder now error is gone